# iTunes connect - Cannot add users - invitation email not sent

Tags: app-store-connect, testflight

When I add a user in *iTunes Connect > Users and Roles > iTunes connect users > +* (add user)

Itunes connect says *"A verificartion email has been sent to..."* (see screenshot) but the **email is never received** (even in spam folder). I am unable to add users to my itunes connect as a result because they cannot activate their accounts.

**This problem occurs with any email I try (including newly created ones without iTunes accounts)**

Does anyone know a way around this or why this may be happening ?

[image]

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue right now since yesterday, no email whatsoever!

Comment: And it looks like we're not alone: https://twitter.com/search?f=realtime&q=itunes%20connect&src=typd

Comment: Somethings up, no emails at all.

Comment: I have contacted iTunes connect and they are working on the issue. Will update when resolved.

Comment: Yes, there is a problem at Apple, no emails are sent, no invitations to test flight and no confirmation emails. Hope they fix it fast!

Comment: Good news! iTunes Connect seems to have resolved this issue as I just received all those pending emails. Thanks.

Comment: Is this happening again, Jan 2016?

Comment: I'm also having this issue with an Apple ID that contains "@mac.com" or "@icloud.com". I tried both. But when I try it with my other Apple ID that ends in "@gmail.com", I receive the invitation. Why?

Answer (score -1):

I think this issue is solved by Apple now and I got all queued email 4-6hrs back

Comment: I dont know if it has been back up, but today I havent got any emails out. But I doubt it could have been down this long.